# why are my scanf statements not working?

Tags: c, scanf

I am a beginner but I have been working on this code for a week now and I cannot get my `scanf` functions to work. All of my `printf` functions output just fine but if I go to input my information to test my code I do not get anything. Am I missing something simple here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
float average(float a[]);
int main ()
{
    /* variable definition: */
    char personsName[100];
    char personsAge[3];
    char personsState[20];
    float Age, Texas;
    int people,age,i,count,Avg,None;
    // Loop through 50 people
    for (people=0; people <2 ; people++)
    {

        Age =0.0;
        printf("Enter Persons Name \n");
        scanf("%s", personsName);
        printf("Enter None if this is last family member. \n");
        scanf("%s", personsName);
        {
            if (personsName == None)
                break;
        }
    }
    {
        printf("Enter Persons Age \n");
        scanf("%s", personsAge);
        float average(float a[])
        {
            printf("Average of all family members is %f \n");
            int i;
            float avg, sum=0.0;
            for(i=0;i<50;++i)
                sum+=a[i];
            avg =(sum/i);

            return avg;
        }
    }
    {
        printf("Enter Persons State \n");
        scanf("%s", personsState);
        while (Texas > 0)
        {
            printf("Enter Texas\n");
            scanf("%f",&Texas);
            //Only assign if positive
            if (Texas > 0)
            {
                personsState[count]=Texas;
                count = count + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Print data
    for (i=0; i<count;i++)
    {
        printf ("Texas %f is %d\n", i,personsState[i]);
        if (count == 50)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really have a nested function or is it something with the indenting?

Comment: You're comparing string (pointer) with integer instead of "None" literal

Comment: @SouravGhosh: it's not a nested function, but there are two standalone scopes after the `for`, which is probably not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @MOehm I was talking  about `average()` function.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Okay, missed that. (Good place to hide it, though. The formatting _and_ the program logic are a mess.)

Comment: @MOehm That is why I _moved on_. :-)

Comment: _I have been working on this code for a week now_ - Perhaps you should start over from scratch, because the program in its current state is balely readable. What do you want to achieve? It looks as if you tried to get information on a number of people (without storing it)  and then determine the avarage age and how many people are from Texas. Is that right?

Comment: and I would start over but Im running out of time I have until the end of today to finish this.

Answer (score 3):

The issue, as I see it is with

```
if (personsName == None)
```

This is not the way to compare two *string*. You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to compare the contents.

Also, the two successive `scanf()`s has same argument to store the input. The second `scanf()` will overwrite the previously taken input.

FWIW, `None` is not a *string*, however. You need to use `"None"` to denote a string.

That said, uncontrolled input through `scanf()` can lead to buffer overflows. Better to limit your *scanning* with the length specifier, like

```
 scanf("%99s", personsName);
```

and so on.